# UTF8 not working when Posting

Tags: php, utf-8

Have a really strange problem with UTF8 characters.

I have the following:

- All my files are UTF-8
- I am using (in my form):  `accept-charset="utf-8"`
- I got: `<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />`

But for some reason when i post UTF8 characters like: `ö ä å`
And i then echo the $_GET[] the output show: `���`

Feels like I've tried everything, all help is very welcome! :)

Comment: What you send in the headers for Content-Type is also important.

Comment: Sounds Silly, but are you catching the $_POST variable on a UTF-8 encoded page?

Comment: Yea im catching it on a UTF-8 encoded page, this is soo strange :(

Comment: Is it a IE problem only, or did you get the same behaviour in other browsers?

Comment: Are you sure that your page which echo's your data is utf8 encoded ? Try to place a `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` on the top of your script ?

Comment: Often this [W3C-checker](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/) can give hints about encoding problems.

Comment: Are you outputting those values *before* regular HTML, or within the regular HTML?

Comment: @deceze sanity check was already done, so it's some configuration in php doing this

Comment: @Esailija On a page like `üöä<html><head>...`, the meta header likely won't work. That's all I'm checking...

Comment: @deceze no I mean running the script in my answer as stand alone :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browsers will send the data in same encoding as you declared to page to be. For a sanity test, run this page:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8");
$file = basename(__FILE__);
if( isset( $_POST['data'] ) ) {
    echo $_POST['data'];
}
else {
    echo <<<HTML
        <form method="POST" action="$file">
            <input name="data" type="text">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
HTML;
}
```

Write "äöä" to the form and see if it's right. If it isn't, try to check your mbstring ini values for:

```
<?php

var_dump(
    ini_get("mbstring.http_input"),
    ini_get("mbstring.http_output"),
    ini_get("mbstring.encoding_translation")
);
```

The correct values are:

```
string(4) "pass"
string(4) "pass"
string(1) "0"
```

Comment: I am getting these values: string(4) "auto" string(4) "SJIS" string(1) "1"

Comment: @Elvin change both to `pass` and encoding translation to 0 in php.ini or mbstring.ini, where-ever they are, and then restart php

Comment: @Elvin in your php.ini configuration file, or mbstring.ini configuration file, could be both or either. Search those files and then search for the config values in those files.

Comment: Be careful, not all mutualised web servers allow you to update or override the php.ini configuration. I think you should just set the header with the header() function if you want your application to be  usable on any server

Comment: @GillesHemmerlé true but if he can't change the configuration file, then he has to convert from Shift-Jis all the time and use Shift-Jis.

Comment: Was about to go insane there for a moment, thank you for saving me XXXXX hours!:)

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the insanity that is `mbstring.encoding_translation`, it never caused any problems for me so far. Thanks for making me aware of it. Another interesting idea in theory, yet an annoyance in practice. Oh PHP... -_-;;

Comment: @deceze lol yeah I learned about this recently as well :D It's like magic quotes on crack

Comment: I get `string(0) "" string(0) "" string(1) "0"` using PHP 8.

Comment: It works OK with the "sanity test" example, but if I add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to `form` element, it converts `č ć ž š đ` to `?? ?? ?? ?? ??`.